# basic programming concept: when to initialize new string versus just creating new variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, object, initialization

So I've been programming for a year but this concept still trips me up sometimes. My understanding is that if you don't initialize and allocate a new object when you create a new variable name using the pointer operator '*' that the danger is that the value of that new variable will always just be tied to whatever memory address it is you've pointed the name. For example, in #2 if string is set to '6' because array[1] is set to '6' but later the value of element #1 in array changes to '7' then string will return 7. But if I used method 1 where I use a string class method to allocate and initialize a memory address of its own for string then string would stay '6' even if later element #1 is changed to hold a value of '7'. Is this right?

What’s the difference between:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringwithstring: array[1]];
```

AND

```
NSString *string =  array[1];
```

As a sidenote: I have a tough time understanding how this will matter much because if array is immutable then the only way it could be changed is if a new array is initialized and reallocated with a different value for element #1. Also, once my view controller gets popped off of the stack when the user continues to navigate through my app, if it gets called again all of these objects will get recreated from scratch- so it usually won't matter. But I just want to make sure I am getting the concept anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, whether you use the 1st or 2nd option has nothing to do with the array itself.

The 2nd option would not result in any change even if the array was mutable and you replaced the object at index 1. `string` would still point to the original object.

In the example you've given, the choice of the two options only matters if in reality, the string you get from the array is an `NSMutableString`. If the string is an immutable `NSString` then either option gives the same result. But if you actually have a mutable `NSMutableString`, then option 2 means that your `string` value can change over time of another reference to the mutable string makes changes to the string.

Example:

```
NSMutableString *mutable = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"hello"];
NSArray *array = @[ @"stuff", mutable ];
NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithString:array[1]];
NSString *string2 = array[1];
NSLog(@"string1 = %@, string2 = %@", string1, string2);
[mutable appendString:@" there"];
NSLog(@"string1 = %@, string2 = %@", string1, string2);
```

The log output will be:

```
string1 = hello, string2 = hello
string1 = hello, string2 = hello there
```

See how `string2` was changed as a result of modifying `mutable`.

Comment: Thanks so much, so helpful. Makes perfect sense now!

Comment: it won't let me upvote- it says my reputation score isn't high enough : /

Answer (score 2):

*(edit: per martin R's comment--suppose the strings in the example are mutable strings)*

I made a diagram to help explain what's going on.

The first diagram is your initial setup. string = *nil* and you have a string reference in *array[1]*.

1) do `string = array[1]`. Now *string* and *array[1]* point to the same string object.

2a) alternately, as in *2a*, you can do `string = [ NSString stringWithString:array[1]]`... This will point `string` to a copy of the string in `array[1]`

Notice in all cases if you mutate the array, *string* still contains a reference to either a) the original string from *array[1]* or the copy you created.

2b) For example, let's do `array[1] = @"test"`. `[string description]` will still return `ABC`

HTH

---

[image]

Comment: `stringWithString:` does not necessarily create a *copy*. For an `NSString` argument, it can (and does in my test) return just a pointer to the same object.

Comment: Yes that's true for immutable strings. (Since the string contents can never change it doesn't matter). If you try it with mutable strings you indeed get a copy.

Answer (score 1):

Your string pointer does not remember where the string was at the time you assigned it, so array-level changes don't matter.

The practical difference is about what happens if your array actually contains mutable strings instead of plain ones.  Your first example creates a new string that has the content that's at `array[1]` when the assignment takes place.  In your second example, the thing pointed to by `string` could be different moment-to-moment if some other code changed the underlying mutable string that's in `array[1]` at assignment time.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, hugely appreciated